# MSB3322 on signing assembly on Visual Studio for Mac with pfx

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio, pfx, visual-studio-mac

On Visual Studio for Mac 7.1, I am trying to build a project that builds fine on Visual Studio 20176 Update 3.

The first error on a project file is:

Target ResolveKeySource:

```
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.2.0/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3103,5): error MSB3322: Unable to get MD5 checksum for the key file "../xxx.pfx". Could not find file "/Users/PATH/xxx.pfx".
Done building target "ResolveKeySource" in project "yyy" -- FAILED.
```

The pfx actually exists and is readable.

With more logging enabled, it reads:

```
error MSB4018: The "ResolveKeySource" task failed unexpectedly.
error MSB4018: System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
error MSB4018:   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeEnvironment.GetRuntimeInterfaceAsObject (System.Guid clsid, System.Guid riid) [0x00006] in /private/tmp/source-mono-d15-3/bockbuild-d15-3/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/interopservices/runtimeenvironment.cs:204 
error MSB4018:   at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
error MSB4018:   at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00032] in /private/tmp/source-mono-d15-3/bockbuild-d15-3/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x64/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:305
```

I've been playing around with changing the file format for signing, but would like to have one solution that builds easily on Windows and Mac.

Is there a solution with one file format for signing the assemblies?

Comment: Does your  pfx have a password?

Comment: Yes, it has a password and otherwise then on vs2017 it can not be entered nor imported. I have tried loading after converting with openssl in mono key chain but that did not lead to a compiling project. Removing signing helped of course :-)

Comment: There is at least *one* older bugzilla issue concerning that difference. VS creates a security container that gets passed to the compiler and thus once you enter the password once, the container (keychain) handles it, but macOS is a different apple ;-) and `mcs` (via `xbuild`) only supported password-less `.pfx` and `.snk` for assembly signing. Since `csc` (and msbuild) is being used now not sure how it works now. You can always remove the password from the pfx via openssl, or convert the pfx to a `.snk`

Comment: Yes, that is correct. But should it build then either through Mcs or csc without problems in your experience?

Comment: I only had a couple clients that went signing crazy and we ended using `.snk` files (but drop signing altogether after benchmarking startup/load times on Android). I just recompiled some old signing-based Xamarin.Android apps  w/ the latest Xamarin versions and `pfx` just do not work (unless there is some magic I am missing), but converting the `.pfx` to a `.snk` to extract the public key worked fine, use the mono version of "StrongName utility for signing assemblies" (`sn`) on macOS, `sn -p certificate.pfx certificate.snk`, it will prompt you for the password., use the resulting .snk file....

Comment: Interim note: conversion from pfx to snk is possible with https://github.com/aarnott/pfx2Snk

Answer (score 1):

I just recompiled some old signing-based Xamarin.Android apps w/ the latest Xamarin versions using msbuild/csc and `.pfx` just do not work (unless there is some magic I am missing).

But converting the `.pfx` to a `.snk` to extract the public key worked fine, use the mono version of "StrongName utility for signing assemblies" (sn) on macOS:

```
sn -p certificate.pfx certificate.snk
```

It will prompt you for the password, use the resulting `.snk` file instead. The `.snk` file will work fine on Windows also.